# socket.io not emitting

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

So, I have this app called **server** and **the other** one called **client**, server providers all the data for the client to consume. The thing is, when i try to **emit from server (port 8080)** and **receive to client (port 80)** nothing happens

**server: app.js**

```
var app = require ("./config/server.js");

var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

http.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server side instagram_clone_v01 online');
});

io.sockets.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log("conectou socket.id="+socket.id);
});
```

When the server database insert new photo, this is called:

```
io.emit("newPhoto");
```

**client: app.js**

```
var app = require('./config/server');

app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('Server client instagram_clone_v01 online');
});

var io = require('socket.io');
```

This is called inside a **ejs code**:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});
socket.on('newPhoto',function(){
     load_posts();
});
```

**Edited** with the Answer of **Federico**

I added `io.origins('*:*');` to server, but emit isn't emitting

Comment: Try io.emit() instead of io.sockets.emit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using `io.sockets.on`, I couldn't find it in the documentation. I've tried to clean the code, give it a try.

**server.js**

```
var app    = require ("./config/server.js");    
var http   = require('http').Server(app);
var io     = require("socket.io")(http);

http.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server side instagram_clone_v01 online');
});

io.on('connect', socket => {

    console.log("user" + socket.request.user.id + "connected");

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {

        console.log('A user has disconnected');

    }

    io.emit("newPhoto");
});
```

**client.js**

```
    //io() works only when connecting to a socket hosted on the same url/server
    // For connecting to an external socket hosted elsewhere, you would use io.connect('URL');
    var socket = io();    
    socket.on('newPhoto',function(){
             load_posts();
        });
```

In the page where your user being redirected after login, you should include these scripts:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/client.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this, now i get in the client console:
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MRLJSOI&sid=9P4EcSdT4bXYRwxkAAAC. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)".[Learn More]
Sorry, there seems to be an issue with the connection! dashboard:354:11
Error: "xhr poll error"

Comment: I added "io.origins('*:*');" and solved the problem, but still not emitting, even thou I using "io.emit('newPhoto');"

Comment: @AnnyWalker try  app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));  without io.origins.